# How to creat an instance of an UITableView class in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

**I have got two classes:**

```
//This is my custom class, where I would like to get access to 'MyTableView' class

import UIKit

class TestClass: NSObject {

    //Instance variable 'myTableView'
    var myTableView: MyTableView!

    override init() {
        super.init()

        //Creat an instance!
        myTableView = MyTableView()
    }

    func ReloadTableView() {

         //Reload the current TableView
         myTableView.MyTableView.reloadData()
    } 
    //My functions...
}
```

---

```
//This is 'MyTableView' class which is connected to a TableViewController in storyboard. When I open the corresponding TableView in my App, the viewDidLoad function is called.
import UIKit
class MyTableView: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var MyTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

//Functions to creat the current TableView with it's information...
}
```

**My Question:**

Why am I not able to get access to 'MyTableView' class from 'TestClass'? I always get the exception:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Is there a possibility to get information about the active View?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You shouldn't use variable names that start with upper case letters as in:

   @IBOutlet var MyTableView: UITableView!

That is bad practice, and can lead to confusing code

2. Your instantiation of the `MyTableView` class is simply calling the default constructor on it, which in this case does not instantiate the `MyTableView` property within that class.  You must instantiate it from the storyboard with something like this:

   ```
   self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyTableViewIdentifier")
   ```

Comment: To add on this, the `class MyTableView` should really be renamed `class MyTableViewController` for clarity.

Comment: Okay, that seems to be a good way :) but I don't understand how to implement your solution. When I try to implement your code sniped in my TestClass it say's: " Value of Type TestClass has no member 'storyboard' " So I changed your code to `self. myTableView.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyTableViewIdentifier")`... now I get the same error: unexpectedly found nil while...

Comment: `storyboard` is a property on view controllers.  If you do not have an actual instance of a view controller that was previously loaded from a storyboard, you can instantiate the storyboard with `UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())`